# how to read json string

Tags: json

```
"[\"Key 1:\",\"Key 2:\",\"Key 3:S300KTP\",\"Key 4:K310\",\"Key 5:Kadapa\",\"Key 1:\",\"Key 2:\",\"Key 3:S526KTP\",\"Key 4:K310\",\"Key 5:Kadapa\"]"
```

How can I read this json format?

I have tried as below:

```
public static string CheckKey(string keys){
    String candKeyQuery;
    system.debug(''+keys);
        JSONParser parser = JSON.createParser(keys);

system.debug('checkkeys'+parser );
    while (parser.nextToken() != null) {
            system.debug('check1');
                                                            system.debug('dfghyfgh');
                                                            genratedString inv = (genratedString)parser.readValueAs(genratedString.class);
                    system.debug('gggg'+inv.key1);
                    String s = JSON.serialize(inv);



}
return keys;
}
public class genratedString{
public String key1;
public String key2;

public String key3;
public String key4;
public String key5;
public genratedString(String assignkeyi1,String assignkeyi2,String assignkeyi3,String assignkeyi4,String assignkeyi5){
key1=assignkeyi1;
key2=assignkeyi2;
key3=assignkeyi3;
key4=assignkeyi4;
key5=assignkeyi5;
}
}

public static genratedString parse(String keys) {
        return (genratedString ) System.JSON.deserialize(keys, genratedString.class);
    }
```

Comment: Did you try something?

Comment: why don't you take a look into older post and learn how to create parser class for json object http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/57459/how-to-deserialize-a-json-string-to-apex

Comment: hi i already tired that piece of cod,,it is throwing error like Malformed JSON: Expected '{' at the beginning of object at this below line  Map<String,Object> rawObj = (Map<String,Object>) JSON.deserializeUntyped(keys);

Comment: can plase suggest what to do now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best you can do with the JSON you have is to convert it into a `List<String>`:

```
String[] data = (String[])JSON.deserialize(text, List<String>.class);
```

From there, you'd have to do more parsing:

```
generatedString s = 
    new generatedString(
        data[0].split(':')[1], 
        data[1].split(':')[1], 
        data[2].split(':')[1], 
        data[3].split(':')[1], 
        data[4].split(':')[1]);
```

That's because your JSON isn't a key-value pair, like an object would be, but it's instead a list of strings in "key:value" format. The usual design for JSON would be object notation:

```
[{ "key1": null, 
   "key2": null, 
   "key3": "S300KTP", 
   "key4": "K310",
   "key5": "Kadapa" },
 { "key1": null, 
   "key2": null, 
   "key3": "S300KTP", 
   "key4": "K310",
   "key5": "Kadapa" }]
```

Comment: And if the string actually does start with " then they will need to be removed first.

Comment: @Eric Yeah, I guess I missed that. I guess the real point, though, is that people need to understand JSON before they go trying to implement JSON.

Comment: Thats wise words for anything when developing SF