# Deserializing is giving null values from wrapper classes

Tags: apex, callout, deserialize

Hi All I am trying to deserialize the below response but getting values null every time.

Wrapper class used

```
public class APIResponse{
    public cls_InstantIDResponseEx InstantIDResponseEx;
    class cls_InstantIDResponseEx {
        public String xmlns;   
        public cls_response response;
    }
     public class cls_response {
        public cls_Header Header;
        public cls_Result Result;
        public String Pdf;  
    }
    class cls_Header {
        public String Status;  //0
        public String TransactionId;    //173412791R781092
    }
    class cls_Result {
        public cls_InputEcho InputEcho;
        public String UniqueId; //190178862744
        public cls_VerifiedInput VerifiedInput;
        public String DOBVerified;
        public String NameAddressSSNSummary;   //2
        public cls_NameAddressPhone NameAddressPhone;
        public cls_ComprehensiveVerification ComprehensiveVerification;
        public cls_ReversePhone ReversePhone;
        public cls_SSNInfo SSNInfo;
        public cls_ChronologyHistories ChronologyHistories;
        public String AdditionalScore1; //0
        public String AdditionalScore2; //0
        public cls_CurrentName CurrentName;
        public String PassportValidated;
        public String DOBMatchLevel;   //0
        public String SSNFoundForLexID;
        public String AddressPOBox;
        public String AddressCMRA;
        public String InstantIDVersion; //1
        public String EmergingId;
        public String AddressStandardized;
        public String AddressSecondaryRangeMismatch;    //N
        public String BureauDeleted;
        public String ITINExpired;
        public String IsPhoneCurrent;
        public String PhoneLineType;    //1
        public String PhoneLineDescription; //W
    }
    class cls_InputEcho {
        public cls_Name Name;
        public cls_Address Address;
        public String SSN;  //665108510
        public String HomePhone;    //4698555087
    }
    class cls_Name {
        public String First;    //KIRAN
        public String Last; //MALAKAR
    }
    class cls_Address {
        public String StreetNumber; //47460
        public String StreetName;   //CAYLEE
        public String StreetSuffix; //CT
        public String StreetAddress1;   //47460 CAYLEE CT
        public String City; //SHELBY TOWNSHIP
        public String State;    //MI
        public String Zip5; //48315
        public String Zip4; //5048
    }
    class cls_VerifiedInput {
        public cls_Name Name;
    }
    class cls_NameAddressPhone {
        public String Summary;  //1
        public String Type; //P
    }
    class cls_ComprehensiveVerification {
        public String ComprehensiveVerificationIndex;  //10
        public cls_RiskIndicators RiskIndicators;
        public cls_PotentialFollowupActions PotentialFollowupActions;
    }
    class cls_RiskIndicators {
        public cls_RiskIndicator[] RiskIndicator;
    }
    class cls_RiskIndicator {
        public String RiskCode; //51
        public String Description;  //The input last name is not associated with the input SSN
        public String Sequence;    //1
    }
    class cls_PotentialFollowupActions {
        public cls_FollowupAction[] FollowupAction;
    }
    class cls_FollowupAction {
        public String RiskCode; //B
        public String Description;  //Verify name with Social (via SSN card, DL if applicable, paycheck stub, or other Government Issued ID)
    }
    class cls_ReversePhone {
        public cls_Name Name;
        public cls_Address Address;
    }
    class cls_SSNInfo {
        public String Valid;    //G
        public String IssuedLocation;   //Louisiana
        public cls_IssuedStartDate IssuedStartDate;
        public cls_IssuedEndDate IssuedEndDate;
    }
    class cls_IssuedStartDate {
        public Integer Year;    //2005
        public Integer Month;   //6
        public Integer Day; //2
    }
    class cls_IssuedEndDate {
        public String Year;    //2006
        public String Month;   //9
        public String Day; //1
    }
    class cls_ChronologyHistories {
        public cls_ChronologyHistory[] ChronologyHistory;
    }
    class cls_ChronologyHistory {
        public cls_Address Address;
        public cls_DateFirstSeen DateFirstSeen;
        public cls_DateLastSeen DateLastSeen;
        public boolean IsBestAddress;
    }
    class cls_DateFirstSeen {
        public String Year;    //2012
        public String Month;   //5
    }
    class cls_DateLastSeen {
        public String Year;    //2023
        public String Month;   //5
    }
    class cls_CurrentName {
        public String First;    //JANET
        public String Last; //BOWEN
    }
    public APIResponse parse(String json){
        return (APIResponse) System.JSON.deserialize(json, APIResponse.class);
    }

   
}




String responsebody=`'{"http_status_code":"200","response":{"InstantIDResponseEx":{"response":{"Result":{"InputEcho":{"SSN":"false","Name":{"First":"0","Last":"false"},"Address":{"Zip5":"false"},"HomePhone":"false"},"UniqueId":"false","VerifiedInput":{"Name":{"First":"false","Middle":"false","Last":"false"},"Address":{"StreetAddress1":"false","City":"false","State":"false","Zip5":"false","Zip4":"false"},"SSN":"false","HomePhone":"false","DOB":{"Year":"false","Month":"false","Day":"false"}},"DOBVerified":"false","NameAddressSSNSummary":"false","NameAddressPhone":{"Summary":"false"},"ComprehensiveVerification":{"ComprehensiveVerificationIndex":"false"},"AdditionalScore1":"false","AdditionalScore2":"false","SSNFoundForLexID":"false","AddressPOBox":"false","AddressCMRA":"false","InstantIDVersion":"false","EmergingId":"false","AddressStandardized":"false","StandardizedInputAddress":{"City":"false","State":"false","Zip5":"false","Zip4":"false"},"BureauDeleted":"false","ITINExpired":"false","IsPhoneCurrent":"false"},"Header":{"Status":0,"TransactionId":"false"},"Pdf":"abc"},"_xmlns":"200"}}}';`

APIResponse layer=new APIResponse ();

APIResponse data=layer.parse(responsebody);
```

I am getting null whenever I am trying to desearlize the response.  Also I'm not able to access value of pdf variable. Please advise.

Comment: if it's null, why are you expecting to be able to access `pdf`?  What's null exactly? your `data` variable? Please edit your question to be more specific about what you are seeing, because you can't be getting null.

Comment: @Nick . Yes PDF will contains String.

Answer (score 1):

The reason this isn't working is because your `responsebody` doesn't match up with your class.

Your `responsebody` has an extra layer to it.  It has 2 properties:

- http_status_code
- response

Your class doesn't have these.

Either update your class to match your json, or change your json to:

```
'{"InstantIDResponseEx":{"response":{"Result":{"InputEcho":{"SSN":"false","Name":{"First":"0","Last":"false"},"Address":{"Zip5":"false"},"HomePhone":"false"},"UniqueId":"false","VerifiedInput":{"Name":{"First":"false","Middle":"false","Last":"false"},"Address":{"StreetAddress1":"false","City":"false","State":"false","Zip5":"false","Zip4":"false"},"SSN":"false","HomePhone":"false","DOB":{"Year":"false","Month":"false","Day":"false"}},"DOBVerified":"false","NameAddressSSNSummary":"false","NameAddressPhone":{"Summary":"false"},"ComprehensiveVerification":{"ComprehensiveVerificationIndex":"false"},"AdditionalScore1":"false","AdditionalScore2":"false","SSNFoundForLexID":"false","AddressPOBox":"false","AddressCMRA":"false","InstantIDVersion":"false","EmergingId":"false","AddressStandardized":"false","StandardizedInputAddress":{"City":"false","State":"false","Zip5":"false","Zip4":"false"},"BureauDeleted":"false","ITINExpired":"false","IsPhoneCurrent":"false"},"Header":{"Status":0,"TransactionId":"false"},"Pdf":"abc"},"_xmlns":"200"}}'
```

Comment: Thanks let me try this.

Comment: I tried below code  APIResponse ap=new APIResponse();
APIResponse resp=ap.parse(res2.getbody());  //giving my response values. Can you please tell me how can get PDF vaule which is string value. from this wrapper class. Below code APIResponse.cls_response =resp.cls_response; givine not exist

Comment: Does this answer your actual question of why you're getting null?  if so, mark it as correct answer.  You might also want to look at:  https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/57459/how-to-deserialize-a-json-string-to-apex/57460#57460